# How to pull dependency using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Disclaimer: I'm scala beginner. All defaults works nice for me, but whenever I want to have custom layout/build I run into a problem.

So, as part of my build I need to pull .war(web app) from project A and .jar(jetty launcher) from project B into some directory of project C(tanuki service wrapper).

Can anybody please provide an an example how to do this in the most effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it works with war files, but for making jars locally available you could use sbt's `publish-local` command. Say you have an sbt project "mylibrary" and another sbt project "mymain". If you locally publish "mylibrary.jar", you can add it as a dependency to "mymain" just like you add any other sbt-managed dependency, i.e., by adding a line such as

```
libraryDependencies += "foo.bar.com" %% "mylibrary" %  "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

to the `build.sbt` of "mymain".

If that is not possible you might want to write an sbt plugin/command that copies the files into a given directory. I don't have experience with extending sbt, so I can't help with that, but other stackoverflowers surely can :-)

**EDIT**: <sub><sup>(addressing a comment by the OP)</sup></sub>

No, I don't have a particular Sbt tutorial. If I need help I turn to the usual suspects, the [wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/simple-build-tool), [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sbt), [Sbt's source code](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt). Sbt has an [IO package](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/IO$.html) which offers a copyFile method, which, according to this [thread](http://tinyurl.com/7sx8kr4), comes in handy. Searching for ['copying files'](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/simple-build-tool/copying$20files) on the mailing list also yields other results that might help you.

Comment: Thanks, actually what I was after is a copying file which is already specified in dependency... Btw, do you have any references to good sbt tutorial?

Comment: Not really. If I need help I turn to the usual suspects, the Sbt wiki, the mailing list, stackoverflow, Sbt's source code. Sbt has an IO package which offers a ``copyFile`` method, which is apparently useful: http://tinyurl.com/7sx8kr4. Searching for "copying files" on the mailing list also yields other results that might help you.